# How to handle the dynamically inserted UITableView cells with same identifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm inserting a new row when "+" Button on top of the table view is clicked. It is adding fine. but the cells are reordering when tableview is scrolled up and down. Is there any way to handle this? Here is the complete code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.title = @"TABLE";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Row1",@"Row2",@"Row3",@"Row4", nil];

    table1 = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 360, 360)style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    table1.delegate = self;
    table1.dataSource = self;
    table1.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    [self.view addSubview:table1];

    UIBarButtonItem *plusButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(plusButtonHit)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = plusButton;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array1 count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    }
    return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
           editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSUInteger count = [array1 count];

    if (row < count)
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;

    } else
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
    [array1 removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    } 
}

- (void)plusButtonHit
{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[NSIndexPath alloc]init];
    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:array1.count inSection:0];
    NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row%ld", (long)indexPath.row+1];
    [array1 addObject:newString];
   [table1 insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

}
```

Comment: What is happening and what should happen on scrolling? How are they re-ordering?

Comment: (consider i added 8 rows) the cell order should be always like  " row1 , row2, row3, row4,row5,row6,row7,row8" ,   but it is changing randomly like"row1,row2,row3,row4,row8,row7,row6,row5" after scrolling .

Comment: Try the answer Nirav D posted, it maybe because the condition `if(cell == nil)` condition isn't met if cells are re-used and hence your textLabel doesn't get updated. But even then you should see duplicate text instead of cells appearing to be re-ordered. Try it out nonetheless.

Comment: u checked my answer it will work perfectly. issue is because of reusing the tableView cell. just give reuseIdentifer:nil

Comment: @HemaVathi Have try my below solution and put `cell.textLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` after the if block is it working now?

Comment: its not working

Comment: @HemaVathi Have you set the label text out side the if block check once again that not inside the if condition

Comment: @HemaVathi, i tried Nirav's solution in your code, and that solved the problem.

Comment: I'm sure that you are still setting the text in the if condition that is the reason it is not working Check once as @Rikh suggested May be simply replace whole your code with my one. Also don't set `nil` to  `reuseIdentifier` because this will create new cell every time and increase a lot of memory use with your app

Comment: Both Solutions are working fine for this case . but i have a problem in my project with the similar case . there this solution is not get worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cellForRowAt` method set cell's label `text` after the if condition block.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
}
//Set cell's label text here
cell.textLabel.text = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

Comment: yes... sorry I thought u did ,I don't know what the wrong with people ... they will click downvotes . I am extremely for that. @NiravD

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR May be the reason is you are setting `reuseIdentifier` to nil and that will increase a lot of memory use because every time its create new cell

Comment: yes I know but .. for limited cells it will not effect the memory for that due to size of the cell ,reusable identifier will create new cells.for her case it will not effect the memory size.

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR Don't get me wrong but OP doesn't describe that she is having limited cell its up to coder which way he/she choose

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this:  set  **reuseIdentifier:nil**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
```

Comment: Thank You ... @HemaVathi